# %s wont work with string

Tags: c++, string, irc

I really like the concept of %s,ID. I noticed that this works with char, and I understand that this is a C style feature. I was wondering if theres any other way to implement %s with strings:

heres my code:

```
#include "services.h"

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

services::services()
{
}


services::~services()
{
}

int services::startup()
{

#if defined(WINDOWS)
    {
        WSAData data;

         if(WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &data) != 0)
             exit(1);
    }
#endif

    int addresssize = sizeof(address);

    address.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("69.60.118.163");
    address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    address.sin_port = htons(6667);

    sock = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);

    if(sock < 0)
        return -1;

    string PASSWORD = "password1";
    string SERVER_NAME = "admin.services.net";
    string SERVER_DESC = "Administration IRC Services";


    if(connect(sock,(struct sockaddr *)&address,addresssize) == 0)
    {
        send_cmd("PASS ","%s\n",PASSWORD);
        send_cmd("SERVER ","%s 1 %s\n",SERVER_NAME,SERVER_DESC);

     return 0;
    }

    return -1; //ooops
}

void services::parseData()
{
    char buffer[512];
    stringstream convert;
    string newbuffer;
    for(;;)
    {
        int index = recv(sock,buffer,512-1,0);
        buffer[index]='\0';
        newbuffer = buffer;

        cout << newbuffer.c_str() << endl;

        if(index == 0)
        {
            cout << "Connection was closed!" << endl;
            break;
        }

        system("pause");

    }
}

void services::send_cmd(string cmd)
{



}

void services::send_cmd(string cmd, string param,...)
{
    int bufsize;
    string newmsg;

        newmsg = (cmd += param);

        cout << newmsg.c_str() << endl;

        bufsize = sizeof(newmsg);

        send(sock,newmsg.c_str(),strlen(newmsg.c_str()),0);
}
```

Now the problem is the send_cmd int he startup function (in the connect check) is actually given %s and not the value of password/ server info

It just shows up in console as "PASS %s" or "SERVER %s" - as i said I like the concept of %s is there any other way to implement this, or just use `send_cmd("PASS",PASSWORD);` instead (which works fine, im just being picky)

Comment: send_cmd("PASS ","%s\n",PASSWORD.c_str());

Comment: dont forget send_cmd sends a string as well

Comment: Passing a string (or any other object of non-POD class type) as one of the variable arguments to a function gives undefined behavior.

Comment: It is difficult to see what is being asked here. `send_cmd` is clearly not a "`printf`-like" function that works with format strings like `"%s"` so there is no way that can possibly work, as written. A tutorial on how to convert `send_cmd` into such a function is too broad. **What have you tried** to make `send_cmd` process `%s`?

Comment: Unlike the "\" character, the "%" character has no special meaning to C or C++ compilers, only to the "printf" family of functions.

Answer (score 5):

You have a couple of possibilities here. One is to modify your existing function a little, to use vsprintf, so it can accept an arbitrary number of arguments and do substitutions like `printf` would:

```
void services::send_cmd(string cmd, char const *param,...)
{
    char buffer[512];

    va_list args;
    va_start(param, args);
    vsprintf(buffer, args, param);
    va_end(args);
    cmd += buffer;
    send(sock, cmd.c_str(),cmd.length(),0);
}
```

This shares a problem with all functions taking variable argument lists though: passing an `std::string` (or any other object of non-POD class type) as one of the variable arguments results in undefined behavior.

If you want to be able to pass `std::string`s, you have a couple of other possibilities. The simpler one would be to use a stream to write the data to the socket. To to this, you'd write a (thankfully, fairly simple) stream-buffer class that writes data to a socket instead of the more typical destination like a file on disk. This isn't *terribly* difficult to do, but it's definitely too much to post when I'm not even sure you want it.

The third possibility would be to use a variadic template to support processing arguments of various types. This eliminates having to pass a format string, because it can deduce the types directly from the arguments:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

template <class T>
std::string stringify(T const &t) { 
    std::stringstream b;
    b << t;
    return b.str();
}

template<typename T, typename... Args>
std::string stringify(T arg, const Args&... args) {
    return stringify(arg) + stringify(args...);
}

template<typename... Args>
void send_cmd(const Args&... args) { 
    std::string buffer = stringify(args...);
    send(sock, buffer.c_str(), buffer.length(), 0);
}

int main() {
    std::string three{" three"};

    send_cmd("one: ", 1, " two: ", 2, three, "\n");

    return 0;
}
```

With C++17, this can be simplified drastically using a fold expression, so it becomes something like this:

```
template<typename... Args>
void send_cmd(int sock, const Args&... args) {
    std::ostringstream os;
    (os << ... << args);
    std::string const &s = os.str();
    send(sock, s.c_str(), s.length(), 0);
}

int main() {
    std::string three{ " three" };

    int x = socket();

    // Of course, here you'll need to connect the socket to use it.

    send_cmd(x, "one: ", 1, " two: ", 2, three, "\n");

    return 0;
}
```

I've passed some string literals, ints, and a `std::string` in the demo code, but essentially anything type that supports something like `cout << whatever` should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can use sprintf to convert to a character string and then modify send_cmd to have just two parameters.

Comment: Thats one other issue the more ,'s i has the more parameter's it looks for

Answer (score 0):

You could use the boost format library to prepare your output - http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/format/doc/format.html - something like:

```
send_cmd("SERVER ", format("%1% 1 %2%\n", SERVER_NAME, SERVER_DESC).str());
```